# updating ubuntu 14.04 without graphics drivers

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, graphics

Is it possible to install updates without installing nVidia graphics drivers? If I install them, I cannot boot Ubuntu and have to reinstall it. If it is possible, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set on hold a package, so that it is not installed/updated, using **apt**:

1. recover the package name you want to prevent (for example *nvidia-346-updates*)
2. run in a terminal the following command :

   sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-346-updates

Then you can update/upgrade other packages being sure that this one will not be updated.
They are several other ways to do so (ex: Synaptic). Let me know if you want to know them.

Answer (score 0):

I know we're not supposed to ask for clarifications but I'm somewhat intrigued as to why you 'can't boot ubuntu' if you install the updated graphics drivers. Do you mean you can't or you don't want to?

Anyway, further to the OP's reply, if you want the synaptic way it's 'Lock Version' on the 'package' menu.

Comment: it is that I do not want to it is just if I update nVidia drivers the screen goes black and in the upper-left corner the cursor is blinking